# Middleware to Require Authentication for Local IP .Net Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In IIS, I have both antonymous and windows authentication enabled. In the code, I want to check if the request IP is a non routable IP, if **not**, I want the browser to challenge for credentials.

I tried returning a 401 status code, but that doesn't force the browser to challenge. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this? How could I create a custom attribute, similar to Authorize, to achieve the same behavior (something like LocalOnly) for WebAPI methods?

Here's what I have in the Configure method in Startup.cs:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var ip = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            var isInternal = Regex.IsMatch(ip, @"(^127\.)|(^(0)?10\.)|(^172\.(0)?1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.(0)?2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.(0)?3[0-1]\.)|(^169\.254\.)|(^192\.168\.)");
            if (!isInternal && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            } else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please note that a resource (api) returns 401, while a client (e.g. mvc) will route the user to the login page. Since you are talking about api and a browser that confuses me. For an mvc client you can replace `context.Response.StatusCode = 401;` with `await context.ChallengeAsync();`. But that only works when the default authentication schemes are configured in startup.

Comment: Thank you @RuardvanElburg, you are right. I meant browser because this is mainly consumed by an angular website running on different browsers. It turns out the code I posted works, my application was set up under another application in IIS, and the parent one had windows authentication turned off. By turning that on, browsers automatically started challenging. Thanks again.